# Bookmarklet to run js

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have been trying to create a bookmarklet to run quick javascript, and am having trouble doing so. I have tried

```
javascript:var runjs = prompt("Enter JS:");function runjs() {runjs};
```

Comment: what do you expect that to do? runjs can't be both the result of a prompt AND a function - which makes the third runjs what?

Comment: it seems you want to `javascript:eval(prompt("Enter JS:"));`

Comment: the user inputs JS into the runjs variable, which then could be run in the function (yes, i did realize how stupidly i was thinking only a bit after i thought of it)

Comment: there is an eval() in JS? I thought that was only in PHP

Comment: yes, and it is usually considered **evil** - but in the case of a "bookmarklet" the only damage you can do is self inflicted :p

Comment: Can you put that in an answer, so i can mark this question answered?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i want it because i hate everytime (i do it alot) having to type the javascript: protocol thingy

Comment: just a side question, is there a way i could get it to alert any errors?

Comment: Oh how stupid I was back then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you want to do the following

```
javascript:eval(prompt("Enter JS:"));
```

this will **eval**uate (run) the code entered in the prompt

as per comment

```
javascript:try{eval(prompt("Enter JS:"));}catch(e){alert(e);}
```

this will catch most? errors